# The import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, springjunit4classrunner

I'm a newbie at Spring and this is also my very first question on StackOverflow so I'm going to try to make this as understandable as possible.

I'm trying to make a web service client using Spring and Maven on [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) tutorial:  and I get this error: The import org.springframework.test.context.junit4 cannot be resolved

Here is my code:

```
package demo;

import hello.WsClientApplication;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner; //this won't import


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = WsClientApplication.class)
public class WsClientApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Here is my `pom.xml` in case you need it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-consuming-web-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have tried some other solutions in StackOverflow but I can't get it to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to add a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-test`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I had to add also the version but worked also for me

Comment: @aditzu If you are using Spring Boot, then adding the version should not be needed.

Comment: You are right. For me which I'm not using Spring Boot, a dependency for "spring-test" was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: It causes a conflict in the main class of my spring application.

Answer (score 12):

Now, if you are using latest spring-boot, 1.5.2 RELEASE, @SpringApplicationConfiguration is no longer available, instead you must use @SpringBootTest. Reference here(@[spring boot starter test in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744897/spring-boot-starter-test-in-spring-boot))

Comment: Thanks for the update! I haven't tried it but will keep that in mind for future developments!

Comment: in my case, using Spring 4.x, I also had to change the import to `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`

Answer (score 10):

## Gradle

In gradle this would be done by adding

```
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
```

to the dependencies block as in:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

After that it should be possible to write an import statement at the top of your class

```
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
```

Allowing you to use the annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyAppTest {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Maven so Wim's answer worked for me, however I'm sure this information will be useful for someone with the same problem using Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is answered kind of late, but I had the same problem and I found I was able to fix it 2 ways.

1. I was able to remove the < scope > test < / scope> tags and that removed the restriction
2. I had an issue with intellij not properly handling it when doing tests, so I made sure it was marked as test-root, I changed it from green -> gray -> back to the green test-root and that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to improve in the situation.

I managed to fix it like this:

before, spring boot initializr created a dependency to  *spring-boot-starter-test*  but with the exclusion, like this:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Eclipse accused the annotation @Runwith  to be Junit 4, therefore, the logic thing to do was to remove the exclusion.

Final POM dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>         
</dependency>
```

Comment: I had the same issue today while working with a SBA. Removed the exclusion details in pom and refreshed the work space. It was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes maven start downloading dependencies and doesn't finish.
Go to your .m2 folder and type:

```
find . -name *progre*
```

this command will show you every file with the tag "in-progess", which are the files missing or not finished.

delete the folder and try to update the dependencies again.

Answer (score 0):

In case, you are not using the spring boot, but only spring framework you should add dependency for spring-test.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can check the latest version for spring-test using mvn, and update accordingly.

If you are using spring-boot project than add spring boot dependency, if you are not using spring-boot the below will work, but not recommended.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>   
    <version>2.4.1</version>      
</dependency>
```

NOTE: If you are using spring-boot project, adding `<version>` will not be necessary.