# SpringApplicationConfiguration cannot be resolved in a Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr, using embedded Tomcat + Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used :

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8.

Now I want to implement a Test using the class `SpringApplicationConfiguration`, so I imported

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But I get this error even I've updated the project several times

```
The import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration cannot be resolved
```

I've also tried to add the dependency with by right click on the pom.xml in Eclipse and 'Maven Add Dependency' ,

Doing `mvn clean dependency:tree`  the dependency is there, but doing `mvn clean compile` and `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`  I got `package org.springframework.test.annotation does not exist`

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.ibm.jbatch:com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.batch:javax.batch-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.9:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- com.icegreen:greenmail:jar:1.5.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.3:runtime
[INFO] \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.41:runtime
```

Comment: The jar got probably corrupted. Remove it from your local maven repo and download it again (I'd use `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`SpringApplicationConfiguration` is deprecated in favor of `SpringBootTest`. It was removed in latest spring-boot versions.

You mentioned that you're using `Spring Boot 1.4.2` but in fact I see dependencies to `1.5.2` and this is the reason why you can't import it.

I recommend you to use `SpringBootTest` whenever you want to load spring context in test.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota agreed - this would be a more complete answer with a listing on how to import sprint boot test.

Answer (score 1):

Use @SpringBootTest instead of @SpringApplicationConfiguration