# package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am using dependencies as below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <ant.version>1.9.3</ant.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <finalName>CransoApp</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/public</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <!--<addResources>true</addResources>-->
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::web[] -->
        <!-- tag:: Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end:: Spring Data JPA -->
        <!-- tag::security[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.junit/arquillian-junit-container
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> </project>
```

When I try to run "mvn test" it ends in below error. My IDE can find the SpringBootTest and SpringRunner classes.

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project App: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] /E:/WebProjects/app/src/test/java/com/app/SpringBootAppTest.java:[5,45] package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist
    [ERROR] /E:/WebProjects/App/src/test/java/com/app/SpringBootAppTest.java:[6,47] package org.springframework.test.context.junit4 does not exist
    [ERROR] /E:/WebProjects/App/src/test/java/com/app/SpringBootAppTest.java:[11,2] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class SpringBootTest
    [ERROR] /E:/WebProjects/App/src/test/java/com/app/SpringBootAppTest.java:[12,10] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class SpringRunner
```

How to overcome the test setup issue on the below code?
And I have tried cleaning .m2 directory and re-downloaded the dependencies.

> ```
> package com.app;
> import org.junit.Test;
> import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
> import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
> import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
> public class SpringBootAppTest {
> @Test
> public void runBootTest(){
>     assert("test").equalsIgnoreCase("Test");
> }
> }
> ```

`.m2` directory has the required jars. My IDE able to find the classes. Either way I can't run the maven test with cli and IDE. If any version that I use has conflict over another? I can easily build new project with `parent 1.5.7` and `spring-boot-starter-test` dependencies. But why can't the same doesn't work in this setup? Even debug mode doesn't give much detail about the missing classes.

Comment: Check if this dependancy is present in .m2 or not

Comment: Also check if you are importing from accurate packages

Comment: Your Maven coordinates and your import statements look correct. Have you verified your build using Maven on the command line? If so, then it looks like an issue with your IDE, perhpas you should reimport (or even re-create) your IDE project.

Comment: I tried with intellij, STS and cli as well. Can't able to figure out where am I missing the classes.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in your dependency, remove test scope `<scope>test</scope>` from it:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: if remove <scope>test</scope> this dependency being used by another scopes that they dont need it.i think its better to add @ActiveProfiles("test") above main class in test directory

Answer (score 4):

@Remi, I was able to reproduce your error and fix it. The issue is with an appropriate logging framework being not available. I know, its pretty weird that the logs don't give any such hint. But if you debug this in your editor, you would hit the root cause. Anyway, once you provide the right dependency for logging everything works. Since you are using Spring Boot, it would just make sense to use the `spring-boot-starter-logging` dependency. My `pom.xml` looks like this; with which your errors are fixed. After adding the `spring-boot-starter-logging` dependency, just run `mvn clean test`, your test should run fine.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <ant.version>1.9.3</ant.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>CransoApp</finalName>
        <!--<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>-->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/public</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <!--<addResources>true</addResources>-->
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::web[] -->
        <!-- tag:: Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end:: Spring Data JPA -->
        <!-- tag::security[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.junit/arquillian-junit-container
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Let me try and get back! But the version you are using is 1.5.6! I hope it shouldn't differ much. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it works with 1.5.7 as well. Also, I've updated my answer above to reflect this.

Comment: It doesn't works for me. I have updated complete pom in question

Comment: Just try removing the `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` tag. Maven will by default look for source classes in `src/main/java` and test classes in `src/test/java`. Similarly for resources. It is considered a best practice to follow the standard project layout for projects built by maven. I have updated the pom(along with your other dependencies) for which the test passes using `mvn clean test`. Please do ensure that you have a main class, otherwise the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE:repackage` goal will fail for your pom.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have the same output at he console, but the reason was a little different. 
Basically I am reusing and old test suit with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`. But with an updated version of Spring Boot (`1.5.15.RELEASE`). In this version, the annotation has been changed to `@SpringBootTest`.

Still, the error is a little confusing, when executing the tests, the first error is `package org.springframework.boot.test does not exist` but if you open your editor (eclipse in my case), the error is correctly shown.

More info [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744897/spring-boot-starter-test-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the test class and package was not in proper location and it was not marked as Test in intellij.

Moving the test class to proper Test module and marking the module as Test in intellij from project structure->Module->mark the module as Test.

Already I could see the respective package in my dependencies so it was just about not recognizing the package after correct configuration, It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite problem, in that "mvn test" worked fine after I applied Maksim Kovalev's answer above, but in Eclipse "Run As-->Maven Test" failed.

Right-clicking on the test class in Project Explorer and selecting "Run As --> Junit Test" fixed it.